# Airflow scheduler runs script every second than expected inverval

Tags: airflow

All

I have a python script which should be run by Airflow every hour but it's run by scheduler with less than 1 minute intervals. In Airflow UI, it's shown that DAG has been triggered every hour but in background script running continously.

When I delete the DAG, scheduler still keep running the script in the background. When I add simple hello world script, it runs by interval, meaning Airflow Scheduler seems working. When I run my script in local, it runs till the end and then terminates, meaning script also work fine but when script is run by Airflow the problem occurs.

Here is my DAG

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

# Define default arguments for the DAG
default_args = {
    'owner': 'johndoe',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 1, 1),  # Start date of the DAG
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

# Create the DAG object
dag_test_python = DAG(
    'run_test_script_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A DAG to run pythoon script',
    schedule_interval="0 8-17 * * 1-5",  # Run the task every hour
    catchup=False
)



script_path = '/app/airflow/dags/python-test.py'
bash_command = f'python {script_path}'



with dag_test_python :
    run_test_script_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='run_test_script_task',
        bash_command=bash_command
    )
```